# Error Installing DNN 7

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have spent all day trying to figure out this problem, so apologies if it's something I've missed or relatively simple.

Some background: I originally installed the DNN 7.1.0 Install package. I placed it on a SkyDrive folder on both my home and work computers, primarily to be able to use WebMatrix on both and test out DNN. It's worked fine. I use the SQL 2008 Express .mdf file inside the DNN installation and everything is ok.

I now want to start using VS2012 so I can take advantage of Chris Hammond's module templates, and so I went about setting up my environment.

Win 7, IIS 7.5, SQL 2008 Express.

I followed the 4-part tutorial on setting up the environment; I've run through the DNN Wiki; I've searched everywhere for an answer.

Essentially, it comes down to getting to the ~/Install.aspx page where there is some weird behavior.  On first load it automatically says "Database Connection Error" on the bottom left above the "Continue" button. I don't recall this when I just used WebMatrix.

Also, under "Database Information" the radio button "Custom" is already checked but does not show the hidden content (I have to click the "Default" radio button, then click back to make it appear). Once I do that, I get the following:

[image]

Now, from what I remember, "Object qualifier" is not even required, but this error message is already there on first loading the page.

Long story short, I have tried configuring the DB in all possible ways. I originally set up a DB and input the information. I then tried to just see if I could get it going by using the file system DB in ~/App_Data, but no go. Every single time I hit "Continue" it just reloads the page with the same error message.

I set up a separate DNN folder in my C: drive, unzipped the files in there (yes, I hit unblock first). I load up IIS, create the webiste (dnndev.me), point to the file system where it resides. Then I check the App Pool, and make sure it's set to 4.0 (Integrated is already selected).

I then go to my file system and add a new permission. I name it "iis apppool\dnndev.me", click "Check" and it switches to "dnndev.me", I hit OK, then I check off the "Modify" permission, click "Apply" then "OK".

Sorry, I don't see what's wrong. Other than maybe there is something screwy on my system because it appears a validation error has occurred.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have sorted this out. The problem MAY be that I downloaded the DNN 7.1.0 Community Install zip file and unpacked it directly into the folder(s) I was trying to set it up in.  Actually, in the 4-part video by Hammond, he actually unpacks it into it's own folder THEN copy/paste's it into the folder he is using to run the site (so, Unpack into Temp Folder -> create folder where you want to run site -> copy files from the Temp Folder -> paste into folder you created to run site).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try replacing your web.config file in the file system with the one that came with the download. I have a feeling the object qualifier error might come from your web.config file...

Or open your web config file and search for "objectQualifier" and check if it is set to "" (nothing)

Comment: The web.config in the file system is direct from the download (I unzipped it into the folder where I pointed IIS). It does contain `objectQualifier=""`